# Is there a way to create a variable width header and footer, with a scrolling main div in the middle?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm interesting in building a css layout with a header, footer and div#main intended for a single page app/site. I'm looking to support all major browsers IE9 and up, and all the mobile browsers / mobile webviews (for hybrid apps).

I need the header to stick to the top of the window view (simple enough), the footer to stick to the bottom of the window view (kinda tricky, but not too difficult), and the div#main in between them to fit the exact height that they don't take up, and be 'scrollable.' The catch is, I'd like the font sizes inside the header and footer to vary a bit across devices and browsers, so I can't really set their height (can I?). And if that's the case, I can't set the height of the div#main, which makes it really difficult to place it.

Any help would rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute;` and give footer and header height in `%`; make `overflow: hidden` for them and `overflow: auto` for content div, assign `top` and `bottom` equal to width of header and footer to it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/jX7QL/)

css

```
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
#header {
    background: gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:10%;
    right:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    background: #333;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    bottom:10%;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.test {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    background: grey;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:10%;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

html

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
    <div class="test">
       test div
    </div>
     <p>
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Yeup, this is what I ended up doing, thanks Gaurav! The only trouble with this is some mobile browsers have troubles scrolling inside divs, it seems cross browser issues just keep getting crazier : )

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: fixed` on the header and footer, they'll always stick to the top and bottom of the screen.  You'll need to put a pad at the top and bottom of the body so that hide parts of it; using non-fixed copies of the header and footer with `visibility: hidden` should work.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0;">Header</div>
    <div>
      <div style="visibility: hidden">Header</div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      <div style="visibility: hidden">Footer</div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">Footer</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Static is default. I need them to stick to the top and bottom of the window, not the html doc. Edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Fixed isn't supported in many mobile browsers. Which really sucks. Plus that doesn't help my height problem. I have to do this without telling the header footer, or div#main what specific heights they should be.

Comment: Too bad about the mobile browsers.  But you don't need dimensions for the header, footer, or body if you use the invisible-copy trick as I described.  For instance, see my edit.